# Upsert data into Elasticsearch with a compound mapping id with PySpark Dataframe

Tags: elasticsearch, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, db2, spark-structured-streaming

```py
# Write the data into Elasticsearch
db2_df.write \
    .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/soumendra/chkpnt_files/1") \
    .option("es.nodes.wan.only", "true") \
    .option("es.nodes", "ES_IP:PORT") \
    .option("es.write.operation", "upsert") \
    .option("es.mapping.id", "TICKETID") \
    .mode("append") \
    .save("my_index")
```

I have written a pyspark code which reads data from a `DB2` table and write into an Elasticsearch index.
In the above code, it writes data into Elasticsearch `my_index` in `upsert` mode.

In the above, I have written only `TICKETID`. However, it is not unique. In the DB2 table, two columns `TICKETID` and `CUSTID` together make a unique key.

How can I give these two fields as my `es.mapping.id` field value?

Comment: Thanks @mao, Though that Question did not have an accepted answer, do I need to close this question?

Comment: Try the suggestion of using .withColumn with the compound-index columns , and then decide.